# Cuelinks widget's half part is getting hidden on WordPress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have my website page http://arablelife.com/?p=1369
I have applied cuelinks widget for affiliate program. My website have enough margin at right but still widget's right-half part is getting hidden within layout.

**The widget's HTML code is**

```
<p align=center> <iframe width='300' height='600' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='https://widget.cuelinks.com/widgets/42308?cid=43033'></iframe> </p>
```

**Solution I tried**
I have added following code in style.css at the bottom of the file in webhosting.

```
.sidebar { border-left: none !important;}
#content, .entry-no-pic .entry-content  { border-right:1px solid #E1E1E1; margin: 0 0 30px !important; padding: 20px !important; } /* adds border to right of main content and corrects margin / padding */
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add padding on your sidebar div.
for example:

```
.et_pb_module.et_pb_sidebar_0.et_pb_widget_area.et_pb_bg_layout_light.clearfix.et_pb_widget_area_left.et_pb_text_align_center.et_pb_sidebar_no_border {
padding: 0 30px;}
```

Comment: I added this code but doesn't work. You can check my website's page http://arablelife.com/?p=1369 and check the "Hot Deals" widget.

Comment: bro this is working for me please add **div#facebook-likebox-3 {margin-bottom: 30px; }** margin of this class. And then add the padding on your sidebar. **.et_pb_module.et_pb_sidebar_0.et_pb_widget_area.et_pb_bg_layout_light.clearfix.et_pb_widget_area_left.et_pb_text_align_center.et_pb_sidebar_no_border { padding: 50px;}**

Comment: I go to Theme Customizer, then Additional CSS, added your code
div#facebook-likebox-3 {margin-bottom: 30px;}
.et_pb_module.et_pb_sidebar_0.et_pb_widget_area.et_pb_bg_layout_light.clearfix.et_pb_widget_area_left.et_pb_text_align_center.et_pb_sidebar_no_border { padding: 50px;}

Still doesn't work. I don't know how it is working with you. Might be your pc have higher screen resolution. My screen it 18 inch

Comment: You can see widget in your screen but I can't so I changed sidebar width from 25 to 33 (from theme customizer setting).
After that change I could see widget on my computer screen but can not on iPad.

So I came to the conclusion that this problem persists because of fixed size widget. (It is not a responsive widget). I told cuelink's developer to build a responsive widget.

For about my website's link. I checked now. It is working fine. If you check again it will visible.

Anyway, Thank you very much "TanBir Developer" to support me here.